# onBackPressed() override error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, overriding, onbackpressed

i want to implement Appbrain interstitial ad on my live wallpaper settings, 

i followed steps given on - http://www.appbrain.com/info/sdk-docs/interstitial.html

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AppBrain.getAds().maybeShowInterstitial(this);
    finish();
}
```

Note: eclipse red underline on onBackPressed()

The eclipse is giving error:

> The method onBackPressed() of type SBLiveWallpaper must override or implement a supertype  method

One quick fix is: Remove @override annotation

What is the solution?

Update: Here is the screenshot:
http://prntscr.com/558my0

Comment: show your class where you're overriding `onBackPressed()` method your class must be extend `Activity`

Comment: You already answer your own question `"Remove @Override annotation"`.

Comment: If i remove @override the action will have no response....

Answer (score 1):

As eclipse itself provide you hint to catch solution of your exception

> The method onBackPressed() of type SBLiveWallpaper must override or implement a supertype method

your class `SBLiveWallpaper` must extend an `Activity` class which has `onBackPressed()` method so you can override that method only if you **extend `Activity` class directly or indirectly**.

Like :

```
public SBLiveWallpaper extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AppBrain.getAds().maybeShowInterstitial(this);
        finish();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call super.onBackPressed(); do not remove @override.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
super.onBackPressed();
    AppBrain.getAds().maybeShowInterstitial(this);
    finish();
}
```

As mentioned on the link you have provided.

Comment: if parent class doesn't that method then how to call `super.onBackPressed();` ?

Answer (score 0):

All that @Override annotation is doing is letting you know that the method is supposed to override a super class implementation of that method. If you are getting an error, that means it is not overriding anything and it is just a normal method. Check that you are implementing the correct interfaces or extending the correct super class that contains the onBackPressed method.

Answer (score 0):

Add super.onBAckPress(); in place of finish().

Comment: if parent class doesn't that method then how to call super.onBackPressed();

Comment: its activity class method

Comment: if you are overriding this method this means that your parent class has this method.

Comment: if you havnt extended it from activity then do it otherwise no point in wasting your time in onBackPress method